# Why does & fail to align things properly, here?

Tags: align

```
\begin{align*}
 f(x)  &= a x^2+b x +c   &   g(x)  &= d x^3 \\
 f'(x) &= 2 a x +b       &   g'(x) &= 3 d x^2
\end{align*}
```

gives

[image]

the four equal signs are aligned

But

```
\begin{align*}
 f(x)  &= a x^2+b x +c    g(x)  &= d x^3 \\
 f'(x) &= 2 a x +b         g'(x) &= 3 d x^2
\end{align*}
```

gives

[image]

according to Wikibooks

> & is used to indicate the point at which the lines should be aligned.

why the two equal signs on the right are not aligned?

Comment: This is another place where the Wikibooks are wrong: `&` denotes “go to the next alignment cell”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `align` the first `&` provides the `r`ight/`l`eft alignment point for the first question.  The next `&` can be thought of as either separating the subsequent equation, or you can think of the fact that *each* `&` provides a `r`ight/`l`eft alignment pair.

In your particular example

```
 f(x)  &= a x^2+b x +c    g(x)  &= d x^3
```

The first `&` ensures that the `f(x)` is `r`ight aligned and the `a x^2...` is `l`eft aligned and the `g(x)` is now _part of the quadratic expression.  The second `&` now species a `r`ight alignment point (not  `l`eft as desired) for the subsequent text `d x^3`. Putting an additional `&` skips past the `r`ight alignment point so that the next `&` will yield a `l`eft alignment as desired.

So the correct way to get the desired alignment is as follows:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 f(x)  &= a x^2+b x +c   & g(x)  &= d x^3 \\
 f'(x) &= 2 a x +b       &  g'(x) &= 3 d x^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I think "&=" should align "="

Comment: @user15964: The `&` does _not_ align a portion of the text, but rather `aligns` the text following to either `r`ight or `l`eft.  As I tried to explain it `r`ight aligns the text the way you have it.  Thus the `d x^3` and `3 d x^2` are `r`ight aligned.